# Find all views by id

Tags: java, android, layout, findviewbyid

I know it's not the best practice, but I have a few layouts (only one is visible at a time)
with the same view_id in all of them.

Is there any way method to get all views with this id?
I can iterate all layouts and `layout.findViewById()` but wanted to ask if there is something similar to a CSS findViewsById() *views* instead of *view*

`Activity::findViewById()` returns just the first one.

Comment: other are gone. but I want to assign for example same onClickListener for all vies with the same id.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no dedicated method for this. The only built-in method that could return several views is `findViewsWithText(...)`

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no method like that. If some "dirty hack" exists it will be unstable.
"Best practice" here will be iterate layouts and store references on these views in array.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own. In that case you have to use [`setContentView(View)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)) instead. So your `findViewsById()` would be,

```
public View[] findViewsById(int id) {
    View[] views = new View[contentViews.length];
    for(int i=0; i<contentViews.length; i++) {
        views[i] = contentViews[i].findViewById(id);
    }
    return views;
}
```

Your activity should look like the following,

```
private View[] contentViews;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle si) {
    super.onCreate(si);
    populateContentViews();
    setContentView(contentViews[x]);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.
Just do it in recursion:

For each view check its ID, and do it for its children.

That's it.

After all, that's almost what findViewById does. It searches in the view hierarchy like a recursion, till it finds it.